# How to replace string in a tibble?

Tags: r

I want to replace `apple` with `frui`  and `pear` with `bord`

```
df <- tibble(
      word = c("apple", "apple","apple","banana", "pear","pear"), 
      i = seq_along(word)
      )
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `recode`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
   mutate(word = recode(word, apple = 'frui', pear = 'bord'))
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  word       i
  <chr>  <int>
1 frui       1
2 frui       2
3 frui       3
4 banana     4
5 bord       5
6 bord       6
```

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse option using `str_replace_all`.

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate(df, word = str_replace_all(word, c('apple' = 'frui', 'pear' = 'bord')))

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   word       i
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 frui       1
# 2 frui       2
# 3 frui       3
# 4 banana     4
# 5 bord       5
# 6 bord       6
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, here is another tidyverse option using `case_when`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  word = c("apple", "apple","apple","banana", "pear","pear"), 
  i = seq_along(word)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(word = case_when(
    TRUE ~ word,
    word == "apple" ~ "frui",
    word == "pear" ~ "bord"
  ))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   word       i
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 apple      1
#> 2 apple      2
#> 3 apple      3
#> 4 banana     4
#> 5 pear       5
#> 6 pear       6
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>